# How could I find or calculate the throughput, delay, and packet loss rate of TCP flow from the pcap file, using Python?

Tags: python, tcp, pcap, dpkt

#### How could I find or calculate  the **throughput, delay, and packet loss rate** of **TCP flow** ?

> 1. I want to do it from reading the **pcap** file , and using **Python**
> 2. Now I use the **dpkt** module to caculate the throughput of TCP flow, accumulate the total length of all packets of one TCP flow, and
>    divide total length by (endtimestamp - starttimestamp), is it correct?
>    And how to find delay and pcaket loss rate?
> 3. The data was captured in LTE network.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: What is the problem you are having? Have you written some code that isn't working? Have you tried goggling for, e.g. _python dpkt_?

Comment: Yes, I have. I don't know if my algorithm is right. And I couldn't find the way to find the delay of TCP flpw.

Comment: That's probably off-topic for Stackoverflow - SO is about fixing specific problems with code, not about design or opinion-based subjects.